# Making conditional async call with same parameters in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to make different async calls with the same parameters in React depending on different conditions. For example,

```
 const getNewContent = (payload: any) => {
        (currentOption === myMediaEnum.TELEVISION
            ? (window as any)["httpTelevisionContentRequest"](payload)
            : (window as any)["httpRadioContentRequest"](payload)
        )
            .then((response: any) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log(`current Data - ${response.data}`
           
                    } else {
                        //testing
                    }
}.catch((err: any) => console.log(err.toString());
```

However, I'm getting the error such as,

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.httpTelevisionContentRequest is not a function
```

The error is correct as there is no such method exist on global window variable. But what is other way I can perform this async call ? I proceeded this way as I wanted to call different functions and avoid repetitions. My code is a bit bigger specially once the promise is returned. I didn't pasted here everything to make my question fast readable.

Any suggestion or reading material about my question would be great.

Comment: It's kind of hard to give advice without knowing more implementation specifics. Why are your requests stored in the global `window` object for starters?

Comment: hello @nbokmans: thanks for reaching out!! I didn't stored the request in global variable before these lines. I couldn't think any other option for this.My goal is to make async calls depending on the conditions. As the payload and  return of the promise is similar I don't want to create to separate code structure for similar things. How shall I call two async calls for the functions httpTelevisionContentRequest(payload) and httpRadioContentRequest(payload) and work on their returned promise in one place ? I don't want to use eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For next time please make sure the provided code is correctly formatted, it was missing quite a few symbols.

Anyway, your approach should work. Just make sure that `window.httpTelevisionContentRequest` and `window.httpRadioContentRequest` is functions.

Below is an example of something doing what you describe.

```
  const success = (data: string) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ status: 200, data }))
  const fail = (data: string) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ status: 400, data }))

  const getNewContent = (payload: any, succeed: boolean) => {
    (succeed ? success(payload) : fail(payload))
      .then((response: any) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(`current Data - ${response.data}`)
        } else {
          console.log("failed")
        }
      })
      .catch((err: any) => console.log(err.toString()))
  }

  getNewContent("successful call", true)
  getNewContent("failing call", false)
```